# Selecting all entries where something happened at specific day of the week or specific day of the month

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hello I want to select every person from table that was born on sunday.
The second thing i want is to select every person that was born on 13th day of the month.

I tried a ton of things but i think i fundamentally do not understand how to construct a question like this

[image]

I'm using PostgreSQL

Comment: Do you use any kind of ORM on top of your database ? (like Django in Python or anything else ?)

Comment: No, I only created it using python now i want to work on it using only pure SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to select day sunday

```
select *
from osoby
where extract(isodow from dataus) = 7
```

where `Monday (1) to Sunday (7).`

13th day of the month

```
select *
from osoby
where date_part('day', dataus) = 13
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8ec9401a606db32e97b41686fd4d70bf